# own delegate - function work in 50%, something is wrong

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, delegates

i've got own delegate for my own class.

MainMenuViewDelegate

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MainMenuView;

@protocol MainMenuViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) mainMenuViewLibrary:(MainMenuView*)controller withString:(NSString*)string;

@end
```

MainMenuView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WorkspaceView.h"
#import "MainMenuViewDelegate.h"

@interface MainMenuView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <MainMenuViewDelegate> delegate;
....
@end
```

MainMenuView.m

```
@implementation MainMenuView
@synthesize delegate;
...
-(void)library:(id)sender{
//test
NSLog(@"it's work");
NSString *string = @"some text";
[delegate mainMenuViewLibrary:self withString:string];
NSLog(@"finish");

}
```

WorkspaceView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainMenuViewDelegate.h"
@interface WorkspaceView : UIView <MainMenuViewDelegate> {
int menuStatus;
UILabel *label;
}
@property int menuStatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@end
```

WorkspaceView.m

```
#import "WorkspaceView.h"
#import "MainMenuView.h"
@implementation WorkspaceView
@synthesize menuStatus;
@synthesize label;
....
-(void) mainMenuViewLibrary:(MainMenuView*)controller withString:(NSString*)string{
[label setText: string];
}

@end
```

The problem appears when i press btnLibrary and invokes `-(void)library:(id)sender` function.
console print `it's work`, then my delegate function is invokes, but i don't see any change in my label (placed in `WorkspaceView`), and in finish console print `finish`.

Comment: Is `[delegate mainMenuViewLibrary:self withString:string];` being called on the main thread?

Comment: @ChrisWagner, main class in my project is ViewController, where MainMenuView and WorkspaceView objects are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your objects is set as the delegate so the delegate is nil - messages sent to nil are silenced. Nothing happens.

If it is not a problem, put the NSLog in:

```
-(void) mainMenuViewLibrary:(MainMenuView*)controller withString:(NSString*)string;
```

in your WorkspaceView and check whether the method is called.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very possible, I made the assumption this was done but a good thing to verify.

Comment: yep, i haven't this, but how can i add this? where? please help. When i clicked btnLibrary i want to set new value of label text. i'm beginner. thank you. i try to understand delegates by this code ; )

Comment: In your WorkspaceView in the part where you allocate the MainMenuView, assign the delegate. Example: MainMenuView *m = [[MainMenuView alloc] init]; [m setDelegate:self];

Comment: @Rafał Sroka, but i allocate `MainMenuView`  in `ViewController.m`, `MainMenuView` and `WorkspaceView` are subclass of `ViewController`. please look at this code of `ViewController`: http://pastebin.com/qEti0Bu0

Comment: @RafałSroka i saw now you edit your answer. so, i put `NSLog` and my delegate function isn't called.

Comment: ok, i've got it! i allocate menu in wrong place. so when i clicked as WorkspaceView then i should allocate mainMenuView. i allocate all in ViewController. thank you for help.

Comment: No problem. Nie ma problemu ;)